# finding words with [a-zA-Z] from a sentence using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get all the words in a sentence with regex but only the ones with [a-zA-Z].
So for "I am a boy" I want {"I", "am", "a", "boy"}
but for "I a1m a b*y", I want {"I", "a"} because "a1m" and "b*y" includes characters other than [a-zA-Z].

So for me to get words, I'm trying to check

1. if it's at the beginning of the string, then I only check if there's space after word
2. else there's a space before and after the word
3. if it's the last word, then check if there's space before the word.

So I ended up with something like this in Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+ |^[a-zA-Z]+$| [a-zA-Z]+$| [a-zA-Z]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("i am good");
while(m.find()) System.out.println(m.group());
```

However, I only get "**i** " and " **good**".
Because when I'm getting "i ", there's one space after "i".
So the string left is "**am good**"
Since "**am**" is not at the beginning of the string, nor does it have a space before the word, it does not get returned.

Can you guys provide any feedback on this?
Is there a way to just peek at the next character and not return the space?

Comment: I must be a noob with regex because I can't even answer that. I'm using 6.0 java, and for the regex library, I'm using java.util.regex.*. Hope that answers the question.

Comment: That's a reasonable answer. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about Java regex, so I don't know if it supports lookahead/lookbehind assertions (which is what I used in my answer below). You'll just have to test to find out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your regex engine supports lookahead/lookbehind assertions, you can use something like the following:

```
(^|(?<= )[a-zA-Z]+($|(?= ))
```

---

Here's a quick description of what each component does:

`(^|(?<= ))`: This says "if a word starts here, we're interested". Specifically,
  `^`: Match the beginning of the line, or
  `(?<= )`: Match any point that is preceded by a space, without actually consuming the space itself. This is called a positive lookbehind assertion.

`[a-zA-Z]+`: This should be obvious, but it matches any run of sequential ASCII alphabetic characters.

`($|(?= ))`: This says "if the word is finished here, we're done". Specifically,
  `$`: Match the end of the line, or
  `(?= )`: Match any point that is followed by a space, without actually consuming the space itself. This is called a positive lookahead assertion.

---

Note that this particular regex doesn't count a word as a word if it's followed by punctuation. This may actually not be what you want, but you described checking for spaces so that's what the regex does. If you want to support words that are followed by simple punctuation you might amend that last atom to be

```
($|(?=[ .,!?]))
```

which will match the word if it's followed by a space, period, comma, exclamation mark, or question mark. You can be more elaborate too if you want.

Comment: What about word boundaries? `\b[a-zA-Z]+\b`?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: Word boundaries fails the requirement that no part of "a1m" matches. With word boundaries, "I a1m a b*y" would match "I","a","m","a","b","y"

Comment: aha thanks, I knew I was missing something (by the way, it won't match `a1m` as alpha->numeric is not a boundary, but it would wrongly match `b` and `y`). cheers!

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: Are you sure that's true for all regex engines? I thought in general it counted any time it goes from matching a word char to not matching a word char (or vice versa)

Comment: But a word char is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so `a1m` doesn't have any internal boundaries.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: You make a good point. I wasn't thinking about that.

Comment: thanks! I had to read up on the regex tutorial to understand what you did haha.

Comment: @YoonhoFrankJung: I just added a quick explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use a simpler pattern like `\b[A-Za-z]+\b` instead?  (The \b metacharacter separates word characters (e.g., letters) from nonword characters (e.g., spaces and punctuation.))

The code

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Za-z]+\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher("i am good");
while(m.find()) System.out.println(m.group());
```

Produces {"i", "am", "good"} .

**Edit**
As mathematical.coffee commented, the above fails.  The expression

```
(?<=^|\s)[A-Za-z]+(?=\W*(?:\s*$|\s))
```

may work better.  For the string `I a1m a b*y boy am is!! or`, matching produces "I", "a", "boy", "am", "is", "or".

If in the previous expression "is!!" should be ignored, the expression `(?<=^|\s)[A-Za-z]+(?=$|\s)` can be used instead.  In the previous example, it does not return "is" but returns the other words (I, a, boy, am, or).

Comment: I thought the same but this fails on `b*y` (it shouldn't match it at all but matches `b` and `y` separately).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a note, if you didn't want to use something like Kevin Ballard has suggested. You can break the string into tokens and from there you can check each token to make sure it only contains only [a-zA-Z].

To break it into tokens, do something like this:

```
String message="The text of the message to be scanned.";
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(message);
while (st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
      checkWord(st.nextToken()); 
       idx++;
    }
```

And then you would write a function to check if that token is composed of [a-zA-Z]. Since there will be no white space to deal with, I think you'll find it much easier to deal with these tokens rather than the full string.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks! I actually coded this way as well, but I was just wondering if it's possible to do it purely with regex.